# Check codeigniter query errors instead of showing them to the user

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I check if a query went wrong instead of showing errors to users (containing database info which is unsafe).

Let's say I have such situation where my paging class takes a URI segment to show page 
`example.com/page/uri_segment`.  If someone write it like this `example.com/page/bla_bla_bla` I get an error that shows information about my database.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In application/config/database.php set

```
// suppress error output to the screen
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

In your model or controller:

```
// try the select.
$dbRet = $this->db->select($table, $dataArray);
// select has had some problem.
if( !$dbRet )
{
   $errNo   = $this->db->_error_number();
   $errMess = $this->db->_error_message();
   // Do something with the error message or just show_404();
}
```

Comment: @clami219 but should I display db error messages to user or should I customize the message for user? what is the best practice?

Comment: @MuhammadTarique I guess you wrote to the wrong user... I didn't write the answer, I just edited it (to add a semicolon). I guess you meant to address the author of the answer...

Comment: @MuhammadTarique It is generally best practice to log the error and then show the user a separate, custom message.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this 
`$this->db->error();` , this will get you the ErrorCode & Errormessage in array format.

Comment: Yes using    
`$errors_array['code'];` and `$errors_array['message']`

Answer (score -3):

you could check it like:

```
function myFunction() {
  echo 'Oeps';
}

$res = mysql_query($sql);
if($res && mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
  echo 'Success';
} else {
   myFunction();
}
```