# Codeigniter handle database errors

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am developing a website in codeigniter. My problem is as,

In the development environment (`db_debug = TRUE`). It throws error, If I provide data with an entry with the existing value in primary key.

What I wanted to do is, when a query fails by following reasons: **duplicate**, **foreign key violation**  etc., in the development environment instead of displaying the error, I want to return `result: true` and `message: query failed for some reason` from the model.

How can achieve this?

I am testing with following code,

```
$test_query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO test SET id = 1, email = 'test@gmail.com'");

$out = array();

if($test_query) {
    // do other queries and get data
    $out['data'] = 'some data from other subsequent database query';
    $out['msg'] = 'query failed for some reason';
    $out['result'] = true;
}
else {   
    $out['result'] = false;
    // fails
}
return $out;
```

Note: I want to skip only predicted / mostly occurred / basic errors for example **duplicate**, **foreign key violation**, **primary key violation** etc. even if in the development mode, being aware of possible errors while still in development environment.

I can not use `db_debug = FALSE` because I still want to be aware of other possible db related query failures so that I can fix those errors while developing the application. The reason I want to skip my specified error is, I don't want to break the system flow with these predictable errors.

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600125/check-codeigniter-query-errors-instead-of-showing-them-to-the-user

Comment: Yes I did. The suggested answer that you referenced is to hide all errors for the user. I still want to show some db errors for development purpose.