# Codeigniter: when I insert data I'm getting duplicate key error, how can I handle this error?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

When I insert data I'm getting duplicate key error, how can I handle this error?

```
if($this->db->insert('user', $this)) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

**how can I handle `db` errors?**

**EDIT**

This is the error **presented**:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry 's123' for key 'login'

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `login`, `hash`, `fname`, `sname`, `lname`, `phone`, `email`, `administrator`, `moderator`, `author`, `add_time`, `is_active`) VALUES (NULL, 's123', '$2y$10$EIrEBovWdrSPnMKNOvBuyebUnQKaKNePQSOmhyihf124tompkSnQK', 's123', 's123', 's123', '123', 's123', '0', '0', '0', 1507543679, '0')

Filename: models/User_model.php

Line Number: 74
```

But, I don't want to show it to user. Instead, I want **present the user another error message**, like:

`"Such User exists. Please try again!"`

Comment: auto increment the id or primary key

Comment: don't pass `primary key` while inserting. if you don't have `primary key` in table then make `table id` as `auto incremented primary key`

Comment: @BilalAhmed: id is primary key and auto_increment, but I want to handle `mysql` error

Comment: I need equiv of `mysqli_error()` in codeigniter?

Comment: use try catch there

Comment: @AlivetoDie: I also did not result. Codeigniter auto generate `#1062` error/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843406/codeigniter-how-to-catch-db-errors

Comment: I also tried these code, but didn't help `$this->db->_error_message(); (mysql_error equivalent)
$this->db->_error_number(); (mysql_errno equivalent)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6600235/4248328  or try:- `if($this->db->insert('user', $this)) {
  return TRUE;
}else{echo $this->db->_error_message(); echo $this->db->_error_number(); }`

Comment: I tried so didn't help (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you check before, whether such user id exists already

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('user', array(
            'id' => $user_id
        ));

$count = $query->num_rows(); 

if($count){
     $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Such User exists. Please try again!');
     redirect('controller_name/method_name');
}

// if above one does not evaluate true then insert
$this->db->insert('user', $some_array_with_data);
```

**OR**

```
try{

    $this->db->insert('user', $some_array_with_data);

}catch(Exception $e){

       // this is what you show to user,
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Such User exists. Please try again!');

      // if you want to log error then
      log_message('error',$e->getMessage());

      // redirect somewhere
      redirect('controller_name/method_name');
}
```

Comment: Dear friend, thanks for response, suddenly it's didn't help ((

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov: set `db_debug` to `FALSE` in `application/config/database.php` and then try,

Comment: I have this: `$db['default']['db_debug'] = (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production')`

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov: what's your current `ENVIRONMENT` then ?

Comment: if you set, either ENVIRONMENT to production, or `$db['default']['db_debug'] = false`, then `try{}catch(){}` should work, otherwise, use first solution, which will work even if `$db['default']['db_debug'] = true;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156307/discussion-between-salim-ibrogimov-and-akshay-hegde).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did this: `$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;`.